# BIO_do_connect always returns -1

Tags: c, openssl

the BIO_do_connect function always returns -1. I am not sure what i am making wrong here.
Please help

the following code snippet is return -1 error.

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

SSL_library_init(); //mandatory and missing from some examples

/* Set up the SSL context */
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

if(ctx == NULL)
{
    return -1;
}

retval = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CERTFILE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

if(retval != 1) 
{
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return -1;
}
if(! SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CERTFILE, NULL))
{
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}

if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, CERTFILE) != 1)
{
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}
//BIO Based Implementation 

// Setup the connection
bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);

if(bio == NULL)
{
    return -2;
}

BIO_get_ssl(bio, & ssl);

// Create and setup the connection
// Set the SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY flag    
SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, "buxconnect.net:https/transact.aspx");
retval = BIO_do_connect(bio);
if(retval <= 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error attempting to connect\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    BIO_free_all(bio);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return -1;
}
```

Regards
AH

Comment: Where does it fail and with what error code/error message?

Comment: It means there is some system error. Check value of last system error after this. Means check errno or GetLastError () on Windows.