# Client returns -1 on BIO_do_connect

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to create a basic server and client using OpenSSL and its BIOs but BIO_do_connect returns -1. ERR_get_error returns 0 after that.
I've tried to minimize the code below by just writing // check [condition]. In my real code I'm doing the same thing with an if check and then I print out the error returned by ERR_get_error. (so if condition is true I'm printing an error msg)

This is my code for the server:

```
// init OpenSSL
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
SSL_library_init();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx, &myPasswordCallback);

int certState = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "../certs/cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
// check certState < 0

int keyState = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "../certs/key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
// check keyState < 0

BIO *serverBio = BIO_new_ssl(ctx, 0);
// check serverBio == nullptr

SSL *serverSsl = nullptr;
BIO_get_ssl(serverBio, &serverSsl);
// check serverSsl == nullptr

SSL_set_mode(serverSsl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

BIO *acceptBio = BIO_new_accept("6672");
// check acceptBio == nullptr

int setupAcceptResult = BIO_do_accept(acceptBio);
// check setupAcceptResult <= 0

int acceptResult = BIO_do_accept(acceptBio);
// check acceptResult <= 0

BIO *clientBio = BIO_pop(acceptBio);
// check clientBio == nullptr

BIO_free_all(clientBio);

BIO_free_all(acceptBio);
BIO_free_all(serverBio);

// cleanup OpenSSL
SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
EVP_cleanup();
ERR_free_strings();
```

This server runs fine but my client fails to connect to it:

```
// init OpenSSL
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
SSL_library_init();
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx, &myPasswordCallback);

int certState = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "../certs/cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
// check certState < 0

int keyState = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "../certs/key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
// check keyState < 0

BIO *clientBio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
SSL *clientSsl = nullptr;
BIO_get_ssl(clientBio, &clientSsl);
// check clientSsl == nullptr

SSL_set_mode(clientSsl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

BIO_set_conn_hostname(clientBio, "localhost:6672");

long connectionState = BIO_do_connect(clientBio);
// check connectionState <= 0
// here it fails; connectionState is -1

long sslState = SSL_get_verify_result(clientSsl);
// check sslState != X509_V_OK

BIO_free_all(clientBio);

SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

EVP_cleanup();
ERR_free_strings();
```

I'm sorry for posting so much code. I didn't really find a complete example of OpenSSL server/client using BIOs.

Comment: What is the error returned by [`ERR_get_error`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/ERR_get_error.html)? [BIO_do_connect always returns -1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18450867), [bio_do_connect() returns -1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38301089), [BIO_do_connect fails, returns negative value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22402771), etc.

Comment: @jww ERR_get_error returns 0. These questions didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You server code is essentially this:

1. setup serverBio as SSL
2. create a new BIO acceptBio without SSL
3. accept the connection connection -> clientBio
4. free everything

The server is not doing any SSL handshake here since the serverBio gets not used for the newly created TCP connection clientBio.

Apart from that I recommend that you test your server and client first against known good client and server so that you can faster figure out where the problem is. `openssl s_client` and `openssl s_server` provide such test client and server. Also packet capturing (wireshark) helps to find out what happens between server and client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I have to do BIO_do_handshake a third time? Because I'm already calling that twice (BIO_do_accept is defined as BIO_do_handshake).

Comment: I've tried that but it does not complete and s_client just connects but it does not get any certificates from my server.

Comment: @User9182736455: BIO_do_accept is not defined as BIO_do_handshake. You are using only a TCP BIO in the server. There is nowhere an association done using BIO_set_ssl or creating the BIO based on BIO_s_accept or similar.

Comment: @User9182736455: I would recommend that you start with a *working* example code (just google) and then adjust it for you need instead of trying to do everything from scratch. OpenSSL is not an easy library to work with.

Comment: Thanks I will try that